# How to set an event listener for mx:image to kick in after image loads

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to dispatch an event after Flex loads an mx:image? I'm loading image externally and don't know the width/height until it's loaded. I get an exception when I call width/height to the image before loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use loader, in this case, like i have used in the below mentioned code

private var loader:loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest(rp_product.dataProvider[i].@source));
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,productLoadingComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,productLoadingError);

rp_product.dataProvider[i].@source, here rp_product is my repeater's id,

you simply give the image source here which u want to load, now you have productLoadingComplete() method, and productLoadingError() methods available, even if you want to something on image progess, so use this code :

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onImageLoadProgress);

in this way, you can load an external image, i hope this is wht u wre luking for

Comment: How would I set the results from the loader to the image after it's complete? wouldn't setting the source property for mx:image triggers the image to automatically load the image?

Comment: private function productLoadingComplete(event:Event):void
{
    Image(Canvas(tile_product.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0)).source = event.target.content;
   Canvas(tile_product.getChildAt(i)).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,productSelected);
    removeSwfLoader();
}

Comment: ohhh, i m sorry, i'd have written this function on that day, see this is my productLoadingComplete() function, which is called, when the loader loads the image, just use the event.target.content(which is image)

Comment: i m sorry dear, this is a bit complicated soln, to understand, but it's very easy when we do it, and one more thing, learn it very quickly, coz in future programming, atleast if i talk abt me, then i have to use this very much,

Comment: in ur problem, when we r not sure , how much time the image or external data will take time to load, we use loader, on loader.contentloaderInfo, there r several event listners, like i have used, just i used the in built event listners, and called ma own functions, hope this helps, if this still a problem, i'll give u one demo application

Comment: Thank you Ankur. well explained

Answer (score 1):

you can attach listener for flash.events.Event.COMPLETE event. it is fired when image loading is complete.